# eMMC SanDisk DA4064 got slower 5x

Tags: ssd, performance, sd-card

Recently I noticed my Windows 10 on my Lenovo Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 1 81VT000MGE booting slowly (more than 1 minute).
I compared some benchmarks with benchmarks from 2 years ago and this eMMC SanDisk DA4064 benchmark comparison was striking:
[image: CrystalDiskMark, left 2 years ago, right today]

The slow Benchmark on the right is still the same when:

- I boot from a USB Stick Windows
- I delete 10GB data
- 5 days later

I checked the drivers and they didn't update. Laptop was used 9 hours a day for 2 years with low to medium workload (Remote Desktop Client plus Offline things).

What does this mean? Failure imminent?

Answer (score 1):

Check the SMART attributes of the disk for errors,
If you don't have software for it, try
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy),
which will analyze the attributes and tell you if all are good.

If no errors are found, the SSD might be suffering from fragmentation,
especially if it was heavily used during the last two years and if it's
pretty full.
It might be suffering from the same problem as is supposed to be
solved by
[Wear leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling),
that your data is smeared over almost all the disk blocks, which are not full,
but that reading and writing involves accessing too many blocks.

The only solution here is to backup your disk and format it, which will
issue the disk TRIM command to re-initialize all sectors.
Returning the data will then result in the fewest possible blocks to
contain the data.

Take a backup image of the disk, but also backup all your own data in a
readable format. Don't use the Windows backup, but a third-party one.
My favorite is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).
I suggest creating an
[AOMEI boot restore USB](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html)
in order to restore the data.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree with 'fragmentation' - as far as I'm aware that simply has no meaning on an SSD. If the drive is not crammed far too full, I wonder whether there's an option to run a manual trim. I have that option on my Mac 3rd party trim enabler, but idk the underlying command or whether there's a util for windows that could do the same thing.

Comment: @Tetsujin: If the firmware isn't too efficient, imagine a situation where all blocks are half-full, so that writing a block takes 2 reads and 2 writes. This theoretical case corresponds to the numbers in the answer (not saying that this is what happened).

Comment: I've been looking up spec on the drive. It's *tiny* 60GB & is benchmarking at 150 read 64 write, which is slow as all heck anyway. Maybe the faster results have some element of caching… or maybe the drive *is* crammed full, which wouldn't be surprising. https://www.notebookcheck.net/Sandisk-DA4128-SSD-Benchmarks.636533.0.html and https://www.harddrivebenchmark.net/hdd.php?hdd=SanDisk%20DF4064&id=12396

Comment: Free space is 25-55% (as you can see in the question). eMMC has no SMART. Fortunately eMMC is still working (but with same slow speed).